# How do I change this format to something like 02X-XXXXXXX?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkcomplex(whichcontrol) {
    var passcheck=true;
    var x=0;
    if (whichcontrol.value.length==0)
        return true;
    else if (whichcontrol.value.length!=11)
        passcheck=false;
    else {
        while (passcheck && x<3) {
    if (whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) >='0' && whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) <='9')x++;
    else
        passcheck=false;
        }
    if (whichcontrol.value.charAt(x)=='-') x++;
    else
        passcheck=false;
        while (passcheck && x<6) {
    if (whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) >='0' && whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) <='9')x++;
    else
        passcheck=false;
        }
        if (whichcontrol.value.charAt(x)=='-') x++;
    else
        passcheck=false;
        while (passcheck && x<11) {
    if (whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) >='0' && whichcontrol.value.charAt(x) <='9')x++;
    else
        passcheck=false;
        }
        }
        //end else
    if (passcheck)
        return true;
    else
        return errorinfield(whichcontrol,"Must be of the form 999-99-9999!");
    }
```

This currently brings up an alert if the number is not in the format of 999-99-9999 and I want to change this to make it bring up and alert if the number is not in the format of 02X-XXXXXXX (X's being numbers) 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function checkcomplex(whichcontrol) {
    // You can make a trim if you like
    whichcontrol.value = whichcontrol.value.trim();
    // Check length
    if(whichcontrol.value.length == 0)
        return true;
    // Check if value do not match pattern
    //            Must start with "02" + one digit + "-" + 7 digits and end of string
    if(!whichcontrol.value.match(/^02\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/))
        return errorinfield(whichcontrol,"Must be of the form 02X-XXXXXXX!");
    // It is valid
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, you might want to learn about setting character limits using regex. `\d{3}` is equivalent to `\d\d\d`. :)

Comment: I know about character limits. I just wanted to make it simple for @blackiechan.